# Why doesn't the Stack Overflow home page remember the last active tab?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, navigation

I've noticed some inconsistent behavior between the Stack Overflow home page and the **Questions** page.

- Clicking on the Stack Overflow logo always takes me to the [**interesting**](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tab on the home page.
- Clicking on the [**Questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) button always takes me to the last **Questions** tab that I looked at.

Put another way,

- I can go to the [**newest**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), [**featured**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured), [**faq**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=faq), [**votes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), [**active**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active), and [**unanswered**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) tabs with a single mouse click.
- I *cannot* go to the [**featured**](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), [**hot**](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), [**week**](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week), or [**month**](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month) tabs with a single mouse click.

Is this intentional? Can we get the Stack Overflow home page to remember the last active tab like the **Questions** page does?